# pythonを使って画像変形をさせたい。

Tags: python, python3, 画像

顧客の踵の高さ0mmの足の画像から、ハイヒールを履いたときの足の画像を作りたいと思っています。
そこで、自分の足に50くらい黒点を振って、例えば踵の高さ0mmの画像の点の位置から50mmに上がった時の点の位置を測定して、どの位置の点がどの位置に移動するかを測定します。
そして、そのデータを使って踵の高さ0mmの画像を2次元補間して、踵の高さ50mmの画僧に変換したいと思っています。

環境はPyhton3.6を使ってその変換を行うには、どのようなライブラリを使ったら良いか教えて頂けないでしょうか。

画像を添付しました。こんな感じにしたいと思っています。
基本的にコメントさんのご意見のとおりです。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Pythonを使うのは、変換式が欲しいからです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: タイトルを読むと（伸縮、切り抜きのような）単純な画像の変形が目的であるように見えるのですが、実際にやりたいことはPhotoshopで行われるような画像補正をPythonで行いたい、ということですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

皆さんご協力ありがとうございました。
本件は、別の方法で解決しようと思います。
それでは、よろしくお願いします。